# Ipopt missing cyggcc_s-1.dll and cyggfortran-3.dll

Tags: python, conda, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I need to run a integer quadratic program - preferably using free/open source tools - and have settled on using Ipopt with pyomo.

I'm using Windows 10, and have found installation of ipopt difficult, but it seems that using anaconda is the simplest way.

I've installed ipopt with

> conda install -c conda-forge ipopt
> which seems to have worked.

However, running a small optimization problem (see below) raises:

> The code execution cannot proceed because cyggcc_s-1.dll was not found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

> The code execution cannot proceed because cyggfortran-3.dll was not found.  Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The problem I am running is

```
from pyomo.environ import *
m = ConcreteModel()
m.x = Var()
m.c = Constraint(expr=m.x >= 2)
m.o = Objective(expr=m.x)
s = SolverFactory('ipopt')
s.options['fixed_variable_treatment'] = 'make_parameter'
s.solve(m, tee=True, keepfiles=True)
```

There are various guides for installing ipopt on Windows, but nothing I've found authoritative.  I've seen reference to needing to install Intel Fortran compilers, but haven't found where to get these, and am wondering if that's my problem.

Comment: Works for me...well aside from the fact that IPOPT says `'fixed_variable_treatment'` is not a valid key. I used [this YAML](https://gist.github.com/mfansler/97783e5cb74245924c8fe840cea2f5ff) to create the env (`conda env create -f so-ipopt.yaml`), activated it (`conda activate so-ipopt`), then started Python and ran you example. However, I'm not on Windows, so hopefully you can find another Windows user to try it.

Comment: ipopt is about continuous optimization, you know that right (no integers!)? I'm just mentioning this, because you probably need Bonmin which, in general, is even worse in regards to ease-of-install. Having said that, i remember pyomo being focused on file-based solver calls, right? Meaning: write instance, run binary on the instance. In this case, just use [AMPL's binaries](https://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source/) (ipopt, bonmin, couenne; pick your poison)

Comment: The libs that are missing look like a GCC and a Fortran runtime library of Cygwin. Maybe the Conda people forgot to include them or forgot to set an option so that they wouldn't be required. There are other places where to find prebuild Ipopt binaries, see, e.g., the README.md of Ipopt.
The option fixed_variable_treatment is not available via AMPL directly (but will be with Ipopt 3.14). You would need an extra ipopt.opt parameter file to set this (though 'make_parameter' is the default anyway).